# Combine two core data applications! Iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data, persistent-storage

Just preparing myself for a task that i feel could be quite troublesome, and just wanted to get any advice or pointers on where i may fall over with this task.

I have two "mini" applications, they both use core data as a persistent storage solution.  I am going to combine these two apps to make a "Medium" sized app :)

Is there anything i should be looking out for when combining two apps that implement core data as their persistent storage solution.

All tips and advice welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not merge the datasets you should keep two separate ManagedObjectContexts and make sure that you specify the URL for the Object Model rather than using the merge methods. If you do not specify the model for each managedObjectContext the persistentStores will be incompatible as they do not correspond to the merged model, but to the individual models.